# Trying to add javascript to .ascx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Hi I have been testing the following javascript code on an .aspx page:
I need to deploy it to run on a sublayout .ascx. Now, I know I can add my javascript between the  tags, but when I ran it on the .aspx page I also had the Javascript run based on a certain load criteria, using the "onload" property and SetTimeOut ... I think I can get the JS to run on he .ascx page, but how do I getthe onload to work in .ascx : here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


      function showModal() {

      <%
       RoleItem roleItem = MeauUserSecurity.GetSupportCenterUserRole(Sitecore.Context.User);
          if (roleItem.ID == RoleItem.GetEmployeesRole().ID || roleItem.ID == RoleItem.GetSupportCenterAdministratorRole().ID)
            { 


     %>
        var url = document.URL;
      //  var popUp = '<%=Url %>/components/supportcenter/feedback.aspx?value=';
        var popUp = 'http://local.meau.com/components/supportcenter/feedback.aspx?value=';
        var site = popUp + url;
        var runpopUp = 50;
        if (runpopUp >= Math.random() * 100 ) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.fancybox({
                'width': 500,
                'height': '55%',
                'autoScale': false,
                'transitionIn': 'none',
                'transitionOut': 'none',
                'type': 'iframe',
                'href': site,
                'showCloseButton': false,
                'title': 'We Request your Feedback'

            });

        });
        }
       <%
     }
      %>
    }





    // If the user tries to exit, run showModal
  //  window.onbeforeunload = showModal();
</script>
```

Comment: here is the onload code:<body onload="javascript:setTimeout('showModal()', 6000)">

Answer (score 0):

I think you are following a very bad pattern here... You're better off splitting your JS and your content.  The example below is using jQuery for events...

```
<%-- MyAscxName.ascx 
    Set a class for the ascx, and add in a property from the ascx's code behind definition
--%>
<div class="MyAscxName" data-someprop="<%:SomePropertyValue%>" >
  ..other controls...
  <asp:Button ... CssClass="ActionButton" />
</div>
```

Inside your masterpage, expose the application's base path.

```
<script>var basePath = '<%=Url.Content("~/")%>';</script>
```

Then, you can include your related JS in your bundle of JS for the site, or that section of the site...

```
//MyAscxName.js
(function($){

  $(document).ready(initialize);

  function initialize() {
    var instances = $(".MyAscxName");
    //check for instances of your control...
    if (instances.length == 0) return; //no instances of said control

    //delegate events for internal items
    instances.delegate('.ActionButton','click',handleActionButtonClick);

    instances.each(function(){
      var instance = $(this); //rewrap single instance in jquery object
      if (instance.attr("data-someprop") == "go") {
        //do something here
      }
    });
  }

  function handleActionButtonClick(e) {
    //example url construction
    var url = basePath 
      + 'components/supportcenter/feedback.aspx?value=' 
      + encodeURIComponent(location.toString())
      ;

    //do something...
  }
}(jQuery))
```

By following the conventions above, you can include the script globally, or for that section and rely on the ascx's markup for event binding.

Comment: Thank you for helping, I do appreciate it.

Comment: Quite welcome, I know it may not be exactly what you are looking for, but following the approach tends to work well.  (also corrected some markup issues).